# How do I move UIImageView closer to left edge of the UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have this tableview:

[image: tableview]

These are all custom - static cells.

But in the sim/device it looks like this:

[image]

I populate the cells like so:

```
#pragma mark - TableView Cell Methods
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"] autorelease];


    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Usar mi ubicacion actual.jpg"];
            break;
        case 1:

            break;
        case 2:
            [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];

            self.myCity = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,10,200,35)];
            self.myCity.text = @"Seleccione su ciudad...";
            self.myCity.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:self.myCity];                
            //Call UIPicker
            break;
        case 3:
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Farmacias-con-Autoservicio.png"];
            break;
        case 4:
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Farmacias-abiertas-en-este-momento.png"];
            break;
        case 5:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }


    return cell;
}
```

I understand I need to reset the frame for the cell.imageView to something closer to the left edge, such as CGRectMake(5,5,width,height).  And to do this, I need to subclass UITableViewCell which I did (MyCustomCell) and added this code to it:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(5.0f , 5.0f, 175.0f, 40.0f);
}
```

Now this will make every cell start close to the left edge.  But how do I make it so that 1:separator & 2:UIPicker cells are not affected by that?  Can I make those cells regular UITableViewCells and the others MyCustomCell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was about to create a custom cell xib and everything when I found this in the side bar:

[image: Indentation]

which was originally set to 1.  I just set it to 0 and voila!

Answer (score 2):

-First, if your creating custom cells, you should not have the UITableViewController own the properties that are inside of the custom cells... (Specifically for the case 0: inside of your switch method) That image should be contained within your customTableViewCell class.

i.e. it would be `cell.locationButtonImageView.image`....etc

This is the most striking thing I see right off the bat. That is the whole entire point of object oriented programming. An item that contains a property, for this case an image, in almost all situations should be the owner of it. There are some cases where you pass in properties from the superView, but this does not seem to be the situation here. Fix that problem and it should probably clear up some other issues as well.

-Second: if you're having a problem where the image is only showing up after you select an item, it is most likely due to the fact that it is only set for a certain `UIControlState`, whether it be normal, selected, disabled etc.

And as for the title of your question: You just need to move the frame of the image so that is more left aligned inside of your UITableViewCell. You can either do this on the fly in the code by modifying the frame and creating a new `CGRect` using `CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)`. Or even easier, you can just set the position inside of your custom `UITableViewCell` prototype inside of the Storyboard.